# Autofill Field in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

In Quotes module (SugarCRM Pro) i made one field region (drop down). When we select billing account name in quote name then address automatically fill up . I want that region field will automatically fill up as i have made same region in account module . I want it will automatically fetch the region from the account module as it fetch all the address.

Comment: Can you verify your customer account information, and which version of Sugar you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jmetric i am using 6.5.4 its my client account i am working on his server

Comment: Which client is this for? Need this to help get a support rep to help with your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your editviewdefs for that module, on the field array element, you need to add something like:

'displayParams' => array( 'field_to_name_array' => array( 'FIELDFROMACCOUNTS' => 'FIELDTOPOPULATE', 'FIELDFROMACCOUNTS2' => 'FIELDTOPOPULATE2'),),

Replace the all caps words with your fields and you should be ready to go. Keep in mind that relate fields have a hidden field that is used for the ids and make sure that you are populating it properly.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Ale, I would like to do the same, but with the QuickCreate view of contact module : when i quickcreate a contact, i chose a relate account and i want to fill my contact's primary_address_street (and others) with related account primary_address_street (and other). Do you have an idea on How (and particularly WHERE) i could do this?

Comment: There should be a quickcreatedefs.php file that you can use to do the same thing we are doing here.