# Autofill Office Phone in SugarCRM Contact Module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Can anyone tell me how I can have an office phone automatically fill in a Contact when we select an Account name?

Comment: What version of SugarCRM are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should do that automatically. Look in `/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php`, and you should see the following.

```
    array (
        'name' => 'account_name',
        'displayParams' =>
        array (
          'key' => 'billing',
          'copy' => 'primary',
          'billingKey' => 'primary',
          'additionalFields' =>
          array (
            'phone_office' => 'phone_work',
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hello Karl ... Thanks for the reply. I have done the same thing with other fields but is does not work

Comment: Hello Karl.. Can you please look in to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564091/autofill-field-in-sugarcrm/15759241?noredirect=1#15759241 .I want this thing

Comment: Take a look at this URL: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/08/31/howto-using-a-relate-field-to-populate-a-custom-field/

Answer (score 0):

i use version 5.3.3. I want to do the same thing with a small difference. when i am in an account and i want to create a quote, some information like billing address… transfer automatically but my custom field not…

I add in /modules/Accounts/metadata/editviewdefs.php this part of code:

```
2 =>
array (
0 =>
array (
‘name’ => ‘afm2_c’,
‘label’ => ‘LBL_AFM2’,
‘displayParams’ =>
array(
‘afm_timologisis_c’=> array(
‘name’ => ‘afm2_c’,
),
),
),
```

I want the value afm_timilogisis_c (quotes) to have the same value with afm2_c (accounts). That happens when i create a quote in an account with the address fields.
It doesn’t work with my custom fiels? Is anything false? Must i add this code in another folder-file? Must i change anything?

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. i try to correct with some more information. i believe to be more clear now.