# SugarCrm auto populating fields

Tags: php, jquery, sugarcrm

I have created a custom module having field mobile number. It is having  many to one relationship with leads module.

Now, I want to auto populate the mobile number of my custom module in leads module subpanel.

I know this is a pretty old question but I am unable to find the exact solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? this might be what you are looking for, but I'm not sure:

[Autofill Field in SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564091/autofill-field-in-sugarcrm/15759241#)